# How to update the mongoDBOutput data without delete?

Tags: mongodb, talend

I'm using talend for ESB to pull the data from ALM & inserting into mongoDBOutput.but i couldn't update the existing without delete.

How to update the mongoDBOutput data without delete, if data is exist?

Comment: Did u mean updating the data in mongodb if it exists?

Comment: yes, in Talend ESB 6.3.1, there is no option to update. It is allowing duplication.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) in collection [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) query to update the document values without deleting the document.

In reference with the post https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=38439 it is looking like, there is no support for $set in talend. Please check your version has a support for $set operator of mongodb or not, before applying this approach.